# FeynCalc: Why do LeviCivita remain after Calc/Contract?

Tags: packages, feyncalc

In (perhaps even in older versions) version `FeynCalc 9.0.0` sometimes, on the amplitude level, one gets expressions of the form

$\epsilon^{\alpha q\varepsilon^*(p)\varepsilon^*(q)}$ where $\alpha$ is a Lorentz index, $p,q$ are four-momenta and the $\varepsilon^*(p)$ are polarization vectors of out/incoming vector particles (some massive some massless).

I'm sure there's some logic behind this notation but my question is more why does the LeviCivita remain in some terms even after I issue `Calc[]` and/or `Contract[]`? That really does not make sense to me:

In the squared amplitude (after summing over polarizations with `DoPolarizationSums[]` and after `FermionSpinSum[]` has been issued) I can get terms like

$$\tag{1}a + b\epsilon^{kpql}$$ where $k,p$ are incoming and $q,l$ are outgoing four-momenta.

How can I make sense of eq $(1)$ or get rid of the LeviCivita?

Also I should perhaps add that there's a bar over all fourmomenta in `FeynCalc 9.0.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I think I got it. The final `LeviCivita[]` that remains has (of course) only `Momentum[]` as indices. In my case (as in most other cases) four-momentum conservation implies $$\tag{2} k+p = l+q $$ and I've got something like $$\tag{3}\epsilon^{klpq}.$$ Now substituting e.g. $k = l+q-p$ and `EpsEvaluate[]` the LeviCivita I get zero which is what I was looking for.

In other words, unless I define Eq. $(2)$ somewhere and (perhaps?) FeynCalc recognizes this and automatically sets Eq. $(3)$ to zero, one has to set it to zero by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case, the expression involves some auxiliary vectors, therefore it is not zero. How can I tell Mathematica to make the expression explicit?